# ApexCharts how to pragmatically scroll Left with a fixed range

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I am using the ApexCharts library and the chart component with xaxis dateTime. I have a range that must stay at 30mins and also two custom tool bar buttons that when clicked load more data either to the left(older data) or the right(newer data). What I want is when one of the buttons is clicked it should automatically scroll the user to the respective side e.g. left button brings view to the left.

[left Button not clicked:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xKju.png)
[Theoretical left Button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YcAM.png)

What I get is I click the left button and the view remains as the first picture but adds the data to left but ideally it would scroll to the left pragmatically in addition to adding the data and match the 2nd picture. The right button works correctly because by default it seems that it starts from the right. Does anyone know how I could implement a scrollLeft function?

```
 click: function (chart, options, e) {
                chart.resetSeries(); // zoom out
                const range = chart.w.globals.xRange;
                const min = chart.w.globals.initialMinX;
                const max = chart.w.globals.initialMaxX;
                const adjustedMin = min - range * 0.25; 

                var formattedMinX = new Date(adjustedMin);
                var formattedMaxX = new Date(max);

                props.handleAddData(formattedMinX, formattedMaxX);
                chart.scrollToLeft()?????
              }
```